# How do I align list items in navigational menu?

Tags: html, css

In [this](http://inmyhood213.narod.ru/drstrangelove/hotelprague/hotel.html) example, i use the following style:

```
ul.menu li {
    float:left;
    padding: 17px 35px 0px 35px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight:bold; 
    height:20px;
    background: url("sep2.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Menu is not aligned. It should be aligned equally (along the whole navbar).
    How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

the entire menu has a fixed width.

you have 6 menu items (li).

divide it by 6 to set each li to the same width

Answer (score 0):

Try adding display:block; to make the li elements block level elements. That's how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the padding, center align the text of each li and add a fixed-width.

Try this:

```
ul.menu li {
  float:left;
  padding-top: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold; 
  height:20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 142px;
  background: url("sep2.png") no-repeat;
}
```

If you want a larger click area for the `<a>` tag put the width/text-alignment on that instead and make it `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

You're current design doesn't account for menu item names with different lengths, since your current item names are all the same you don't see this, also only the text in the nav is clickable. I would suggest doing this:

1. Get rid of the padding in the `<li>`.
2. Add the `text-align:center` property to the `<li>`.
3. In the `<a>` add a `width:142px` (approximately).

This gives you the benefit of the entire block being clickable.